# Delete NSCachesDirectory files by time they were added

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

so I am the `NSCachesDirectory` to store the image data for the "*x*" most recent images a user has viewed. I would like to have `NSCachesDirectory` programmatically delete all files that exceed the total file count of "*x*".

I would like to do this such that the images added the earliest by time/date are deleted first. Is there a way to do this without actually knowing the name of the file I would like to delete? I know to delete a certain file I can just do the following:

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *mainPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];

mainPath = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:DirectoryName];
```

and

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mainPath];

if (fileExists)
{
     BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:mainPath error:&error];
     if (!success) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
```

but extending this to my use case has proven to be quite the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

When you have some logic for the deletion of user cache data you better implement it for yourself, because you know best what to delete.

[Apple File documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for some details about storing files, with special attributes for backup.